# Fancy slash thing?

Tags: calculus, notation

I'm an early high school student so I haven't yet encountered the symbol I am looking for in school, but what is the symbol that looks kind of like a big " / " but with curled ends called?  Sometimes it has numbers/variables above or below it. I just need to know what it's called so I can research it on my own. I think it's used in calculus... maybe?

Comment: Assuming you mean $\int$, the symbol you're referring to is an _integral_. $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ means the area under the curve $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral

Comment: You mean this thing? $$\int$$ It's called an [integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_symbol).

Comment: Just FYI, it's meant to be an elongated letter 'S' (for "sum").

Comment: This site might be able to answer questions about math symbols: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The symbol $\int$ is known as the **integral sign**. It's used in calculus to denote integration:

$$\int 2x \, dx = x^2 + C$$

$$\int_0^2 x \, dx = 2$$

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x) \, dx = 1$$

As you can see, it's always followed by a function, and then a differential like $dx$. This indicates which variable is being used in the integration; for instance, $\int f(x,y) \,dx \neq \int f(x,y) \,dy$, but $\int f(x) \,dx = \int f(t) \,dt$.

Without numbers/variables, it represents the indefinite integral (which is another function); with two limits or with one set as superscripts or subscripts, it denotes the definite integral (which is a number).

You'll see multiple integral signs $\iint$ for an integral with multiple differentials,

$$\iint f(x,y) \,dy \,dx,$$

or a closed integral sign $\oint$ (not sure if that's the correct name) for an integral over a closed curve, surface, etc. Don't expect to see either of those in high school calculus.

Comment: $\oint$ is called circulation.

Answer (score 4):

It means the area under a graph (or, rather, between the graph and the $x$-axis).

For example, the area between the graph of $y=1/(1+x^2)$ and the $x$-axis would be written like this:$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{1+x^2}dx$$You can [graph it here](https://desmos.com/calculator). It can be shown that this is equal to $\pi$!

On the other hand:
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac1{1+x^2}dx$$
can be shown to be equal to only $\pi/2$. Here, the $-1$ and $1$ mean we only consider a portion of the area, between the vertical lines $x=-1$ and $x=1$.

From a physics standpoint, if $v(t)$ is the velocity of a particle in terms of time (which may change over time, e.g. if the particle speeds up or slows down), it can be shown that $\int_a^bv(t)dt$ is equal to the distance between where the particle is at time $t=a$ and where it is at time $t=b$. This, and results like it, make integrals incredibly useful for physics and engineering.

The most powerful tool for computing integrals is the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*, which relates integrals to something called "derivatives," which you learn more about in calculus.